# Servo motor MG995 keeps rotating when program has ended

Tags: raspberry-pi, servo

I bought the MG995 55g 360° [servomotor](https://www.bol.com/be/nl/p/mmobiel-micro-servo-motor-kit-mg995-55g-360-geschikt-voor-arduino-en-raspberry-pi/9300000053477533/?s2a=) and I am trying to control it with my Raspberry Pi using the following code:

```
from gpiozero import Servo
from time import sleep

from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
factory = PiGPIOFactory()
myGPIO = 12
servo = Servo(myGPIO, min_pulse_width=0.9/1000, max_pulse_width=2.1/1000, pin_factory=factory)

try:
  print("start in the middle")
  servo.mid()
  sleep(5)

  print("go to min")
  servo.min()
  sleep(5)

  print("go to max")
  servo.max()
  sleep(5)

  print("and back to the middle")
  servo.mid()
  sleep(5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print("keyboard interrupt")

except:
  print("some error")

finally:
  print("finishing...")
  servo.value = None
```

When the program is finished, my servo starts continuously rotating or moving to random positions at random times. I can only stop it by unplugging it. What is going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you delete `servo.value = None`?

Comment: It no longer rotates continuously but it seems to have remembered some previous program: it moves to random positions at random times.